# slack botkit - `hears` on a specific slash command doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api, botkit

I am trying to develop a slack bot using slack botkit and i have a problem while trying to handle slash commands.
I am using the following syntax that i took from the support slack of the slack botkit.

```
controller.hears('/tempo', 'slash_command', async (bot,message)=>{
        console.log("here")
    })
```

it doesn't work using this syntax, but on the other hand the command generated from the scaffold works.

```
controller.on('slash_command',async (bot, message) => {

        console.log(message.command.split('/')[1])
      
    })
```

What am i missing here ?